# Use namedtuple instead of tuple with typing.optional

Tags: python, python-collections

How can I use namedtuple with typing.optional instead of this tuple ?
I want to to call the function in the format of  result_final(power=Stats(min=12, max=None))
Thank you.
I tried with `Stats = namedtuple('Stats', [Optional[int], Optional[int]])`

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple
Stats = Tuple[Optional[int], Optional[int]]  # min, max

def result_final(power: Stats):
    min, max = power
    print("min:", min, "max: ", max)
print(result_final(power=(12, None)))

# namedTuple to have result_final(power=Stats(min=12, max=None))
```

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i want to use namedtuple instead of Tuple in order to call the result_final in this format: result_final(power=Stats(min=12, max=None))

Comment: You haven't created a `namedtuple` class anywhere. What exactly is the problem? You seem to be aware of named tuples, so what exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: I don't know how to use namedtuple with Optional values

Comment: What? Again, **what exactly is the problem**? You don't show any attempt anywhere

Comment: one valubale tipo could be: **forget about typing annotation** and focus on your problem, with the virtues that made Python an easy to use language. Typing is *optional* and basically only adds value to complex or big systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Python 3 you can do the following.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Stats(NamedTuple):
    min: Optional[int]
    max: Optional[int]
```

See docs for further details: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: Thank you @Hitobat, there's no way to use directly the NamedTuple ?

Comment: I think maybe it's possible. From docs last example is `Employee = NamedTuple('Employee', [('name', str), ('id', int)])`.